# Function call in loop statement, time vs space trade off?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, sorting

On leetcode I came across many code snippets where the loop looks like this:

```
for x in sorted(vals):
    ...........
```

Every time we reach the for statement, sorted() is called right? So isn't it better to store the sorted list separately and then iterate that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming Python 3)

Actually, it is only called once.

```py
Python 3.7.2 (default, Jan 10 2019, 23:51:51) 
[GCC 8.2.1 20181127] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def notify_sorted(l):
...     print("Invoked!")
...     return sorted(l)
... 
>>> for x in notify_sorted([1,2,3]):
...     print(x)
... 
Invoked!
1
2
3
```